# Why does setting PYTHONPATH corrupt package lookup?

Tags: python, pygtk

I have the following python file, importproblem.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import gobject
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
```

When I run it at the command line as such:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./importproblem.py 
-bash-4.1$
```

It is fine.  I confirm that I am using Python 2.6.6

```
-bash-4.1$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

When I send it to the python interpreter directly:

```
-bash-4.1$ python importproblem.py 
-bash-4.1$
```

It is fine.  I am trying to resolve a threading problem [my UI locks up when I start plain old threads that monitor sockets], so I built a local version of pyGTK, documented as a requirement [pyGTK FAQ Archive](https://eccentric.one/misc/pygtk/pygtkfaq.html#20.6)

When I add the path to that module setting the PYTHONPATH, python then fails to find gtk:

```
-bash-4.1$ PYTHONPATH=/home/dscoughl/lib64/python2.6/site-packages python 
importproblem.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importproblem.py", line 5, in <module>  
      import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
-bash-4.1$
```

How do I resolve this or diagnose it further?

Comment: I copied the gtk-2.0 directory over from the system location: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0 and it now finds it, and uses it (and doesn't solve my threading problem), but my question is really about why PYTHONPATH breaks the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH tells Python where to look for its libraries. If the library is not under PYTHONPATH, it is not going to find it.

A better way to handle this sort of thing is to leave PYTHONPATH as a whole pointing to the system packages, and then use virtualenv.

The default way to set this up is to make sure that pip is installed for your distribution and python version, then run

```
pip install virtualenv
```

pip may be pip2 or pip3 instead depending on your distro and its default assumptions about python.

Then to create the virtual environment for your project, go to a folder that you can relatively easily reference and execute:

```
virtualenv projectenv
```

Replace projectenv with the folder name that you want it to create the environment in.

This will create a virtual environment using your system's default Python install. If you have multiple version of python, and you want to use something other than the default, then use the following.

```
virtualenv projectenv -p PYTHON_EXE
or
virtualenv projectenv --PYTHON=PYTHON_EXE
```

PYTHON_EXE will be the name of the binary for the correct version of python. For instance on a newer system you may need to use --PYTHON=python2 in order to use version 2.6 rather than version 3.x.

To activate the virtual environment, depending on your distro and shell, use one of the following:

```
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
or
./path/to/ENV/bin/activate
```

Relative paths are generally ok. This will take you into the virtual execution environment.

From there you can use pip to install the packages that you want. My first step is often to upgrade pip itself within the environment.

When you are ready to stop using the virtual environment, just use:

```
deactivate
```

exiting the shell session will do the trick as well, but if you are accessing a remote system it is good to know the proper way.

Check out the documentation here for more thorough information on virtualenv, including how to use it on a Windows system: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

There is plenty of information on the web about how to use virtualenv, including on using it with Apache2 and Nginx for web development. Most python web frameworks will have instructions for using virtualenv.